# Durandal: Get Current Page URL using route

Tags: durandal

In my current case, I need to fetch the current URL params for logic. I am using the following code to get the current URL in JavaScript.

```
window.location.href.toString()
```

I was suggested by my senior developer asked me to check for the getting the current URL using Durandal route element. I have searched few SO questions, But could not get the correct solution.

EDIT:

Sample URL:

> http://localhost:64100/#/sample/moduleName?token=0df16b9b-73c8-45cb-83e8-7adf66ab9570

I can able to read the module name using,

```
router.activeInstruction().config.moduleId;
```

Can anyone suggest me how to read that token value Eg: 0df16b9b-73c8-45cb-83e8-7adf66ab9570 ?

Any help would be useful!

Comment: At what point do you need the token value?  is it during composition, view activation, etc? This article on the DurandalJs documentation site might help) - http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html

Answer (score 0):

The activeInstruction() object contains a `queryString` and `queryParams` which may have the information you are looking for.

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api.html#class/Router/property/activeInstruction